# JSON like string with unicode to valid JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unicode

I get a string which resembles JSON and I'm trying to convert it to valid JSON using python.
It looks like this example, but the real data gets very long:

```
{u'key':[{
       u'key':u'object',
       u'something':u'd\xfcabc',
       u'more':u'\u2023more',
       u'boolean':True
    }]
}
```

So there are also a lot of special characters, as well as the "wrong" boolean which should be just lowercase letters.
I don't have any influence over the data I get, I just have to parse it somehow and extract some stuff from it.
I tried to replace the special characters and everything and force it to be a valid JSON, but it is not at all elegant and I could easily forget to replace one type of special character.

Comment: Can you confirm if there is a colon ':' between the first key `key` and the data? `{u'key'[{`

Comment: You are right, there is a colon. Corrected.

Comment: This is not JSON at all, but the repr of a Python dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `literal_eval` from the `ast` module for this.

`ast.literal_eval(yourString)`

You can then convert this Object back to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

JSON spec only allows javascript data (`true`, `false` for booleans, `null`, `undefined` for `None` properties, etc)
The string of this question, it's an python object, so as @florian-dreschsler says, you must use `literal_eval` from the `ast` module

```
>>> import ast
>>> json_string = """
... {u'key':[{
...        u'key':u'object',
...        u'something':u'd\xfcabc',
...        u'more':u'\u2023more',
...        u'boolean':True,  #this property fails with json module
...        u'null':None,     #this property too
...     }]
... }
... """
>>> ast.literal_eval(json_string)
{u'key': [{u'boolean': True, u'null': None, u'something': u'd\xfcabc', u'key': u'object', u'more': u'\u2023more'}]}
```